# Azure Data Factory import from SAP HANA - Performance Issues

Tags: azure-data-factory, hana

We are importing SAP HANA Objects via the adf SAP HANA connector and write to an ADLS gen2. The Throughput is < 2mbit/s. The issue is (our findings), that adf requests many small packages. We tested and ruled out that it's an infrastructure error.

The only options from the adf side to fiddle with are 'Partition option' and 'Packet size (KB)'. We tested both and they dont have any impact on the speed importing the big view in question.

screen_1: adf copy data source settings
[image: adf copy data source settings]

screen_2: adf copy file details
[image: adf copy file details]

Does anyone had a similar experience and some wise words to share here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try increasing the parallelism. According to doc,

- When copying data from partition-option-enabled data store (including Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, Azure Synapse Analytics, Oracle, Amazon RDS for Oracle, Netezza, SAP HANA, SAP Open Hub, SAP Table, SQL Server, Amazon RDS for SQL Server and Teradata), default parallel copy is 4.

try increasing the node count on your SHIR, increase your parallelism or size. (Scale up or out)

If you copy data from partition-option-enabled data stores (like SAP HANA), consider to gradually tune the parallel copies, note that too many parallel copies may even hurt the performance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-copy-activity-on-self-hosted-ir

Have you been into this documentation?

If the suggestions in the docs dont fix your issue, and you tried a lot of things already. Think whether the SAP HANA is the bottleneck here. Also note that, it takes some time for the copy speed to eventually increase and reach peak levels.

For me to help you, you should try all these steps in the docs, and then list what has not worked for you so far.

---

Aaand.. most importantly:

Here are more details how to scale up or scale out the Self-hosted IR:

If the CPU and available memory on the Self-hosted IR node are not fully utilized, but the execution of concurrent jobs is reaching the limit, you should scale up by increasing the number of concurrent jobs that can run on a node. See here for instructions.
If on the other hand, the CPU is high on the Self-hosted IR node or available memory is low, you can add a new node to help scale out the load across the multiple nodes. See here for instructions.
Note in the following scenarios, single copy activity execution can leverage multiple Self-hosted IR nodes:

Copy data from file-based stores, depending on the number and size of the files.
Copy data from partition-option-enabled data store (including Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, Azure Synapse Analytics, Oracle, Netezza, SAP HANA, SAP Open Hub, SAP Table, SQL Server, and Teradata), depending on the number of data partitions.

Comment: We already have and it does not affect the throughput and yes, we have been through this documentation. The bottleneck seems to be the package size and the option where we can adjust this (screen 1) does not have an effect on it.

Comment: What about the location of the SAP HANA ? is SHIR hosted in close proximity? 

Btw, the packet size I see is very big, normally the default is 2048 kbs. Increasing this size did not change anything in speed?

Comment: I already stated, we tested and ruled out infrastructure issues. Connection speed could be 1gbit. No, fiddling with the packet size and partition option did not change anything.

Comment: Alright... I assume you already tried running multiple copy activities in parallel or in a foreach loop for different sections of the data to run at the same time.. if this didn't work for you as well, hope someone else here would be able to help.